# interpreting regular expression in perl

Tags: regex, string, perl, string-matching

I am trying to reverse engineer a Perl script.  One of the lines contains a matching operator that reads:

```
$line =~ /^\s*^>/
```

The input is just FASTA sequences with header information.  The script is looking for a particular pattern in the header, I believe.

Here is an example of the files the script is applied to:

```
>mm9_refGene_NM_001252200_0 range=chr1:39958075-39958131 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ 
repeatMasking=none
ATGGCGAACGACTCTCCCGCGAAGAGCCTGGTGGACATTGACCTGTCGTC
CCTGCGG

>mm9_refGene_NM_001252200_1 range=chr1:39958354-39958419 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ 
repeatMasking=none
GACCCTGCTGGGATTTTTGAGCTGGTGGAAGTGGTTGGAAATGGCACCTA
TGGACAAGTCTATAAG
```

This is a matching operator asking whether the line, from its beginning, contains white spaces of at least more than zero, but then I lose its meaning.

This is how I have parsed the regex so far:

from beginning [ (/^... ], contains white spaces [ ...\s... ] of at least more than zero [ ...*... }.

Comment: what is the final ^ for?

Comment: ^ does not appear in the headers after any whitespaces. So, the ^ symbol must be modifying something in the regex.  I don't understand what it is doing. A whitespace followed by a ^ means what?

Comment: @BoristheSpider - I believe `^` will only be matched as a literal if it's escaped (`\^`).

Comment: Since fasta records always begin with a ">", one way to tell when a new record is encountered is to `/^>/`.  I suspect that the author of `/^\s*^>/` meant `/^>/`, since the author's also matches the beginning of a fasta record.  You'll see `/^>/` in many bioinformatics Perl scripts for just this purpose.

Comment: ahh, @Kenosis, you've been very helpful in the past! Do you agree that the regex, as originally written, is not only looking for > but is also looking for typos or extra whitespace preceding >?

Comment: @ES55 - Thank you.  I believe its only purpose is to match the start of a fasta record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com) (or, as [r3mus said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555921/interpreting-regular-expression-in-perl/20556001#comment30742603_20556001), [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/), which is free):

```
Assert position at the beginning of the string «^»
Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, and line breaks) «\s*»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
Assert position at the beginning of the string «^»
Match the character “>” literally «>»
```

EDIT: [Birei's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20556039/1454048) is probably more correct if the regex in question is actually wrong.

Comment: you solved its meaning using the RegexBuddy website?

Comment: No, it's a Windows application I use. Super nice for building, testing, and understanding regexes.

Comment: @r3mus - Yup, very true. That said, I bought it yeaaarrrrrrs ago and it's definitely paid off (and all updates are free).

Comment: the regex as written in the question is how it is written in the script, which actually works just fine (though I am learning just how).  The regex101.com site told me it means essentially what your answers conveys.

Answer (score 2):

You have to get rid of the second `^` character. It is a metacharacter and means the beginning of a line (without special flags like `/m`), but that meaning it's already achieved with the first one.

The character `>` will match at the beginning of the line without the second `^` because the initial whitespace is optional (`*` quantifier). So, use:

```
$line =~ /^\s*>/
```

Comment: the script I have works, so if you are correct, perhaps the second ^ is redundant, or else the first part of the regex is useless?  I see now that the point of this regex is to find lines that being with >.  So, my interpretation of the original regex is to find lines that contain whitespaces, then go back to beginning of the line (the second ^) and try to match the >.  Correct?

Comment: @ES55: As I understand it, yes, it's correct. The second `^` is redundant but not the first part. I guess it tries to also match a line that has whitespace before the first character `>`, perhaps for typos, malformed ones, or something like that.

Comment: i did not notice that.  i think you are right, it is looking for typos and the like!

Answer (score 2):

It is much easier to reverse engineer perl script with debugger. 
"perl -d script.pl" or if you have Linux ddd: "ddd cript.pl &".

For multiline regex this regex match for emptyline with spaces and begin of the next FASTA.
http://www.rexfiddle.net/c6locQg